# PHP OpenLog does not log to specific Facility

Tags: php, syslog

I have a PHP page that I want to have errors and info logged to a file. I setup the OpenLog and Syslog functions and they work, but they only log to the Syslog and not to the facility I defined (example below).

```
<?php
Openlog("PHP-Page", LOG_NDELAY, LOG_LOCAL5);
// Code Here
Syslog(LOG_INFO, "User logged in from $rip.");
// More Code
Closelog();
?>
```

Everything else in the page works as it should, except for the logging location. The logging shows up as I wanted, but it doesn't log to Local5 only Syslog. I am on Debian 7 running LigHTTPd 1.4.31 and PHP 5.4.36. Below is the entry in my rsyslog.conf.

```
local5.*        /var/log/phppage.log
```

The permissions on the file are as follows.

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root        root          0 Mar  4 04:02 phppage.log
```

I use Webmin to manage the server and it created the log file when I set it up in Syslog from Webmin. Webmin also generate the rsyslog entry.

Any thoughts on why this is happening? I haven't been able to find anything to indicate a write error or anything like that.

Comment: have you restarted the syslog daemon?

Comment: I thought I had. I guess Webmin's Apply button doesn't restart the service, but it has worked on other syslog setups I did, odd. It appears to be logging into the correct file now, but it also shows up in the syslog, anyway to prevent that?

Comment: You can use the syslog config file to filter  user5 out of `/var/log/syslog` and log it only to a separate file.